# dataframe datetimeindex changes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a dataframe with a date column. I want to turn this date column into my index. When I change the date column into `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='raise', dayfirst=True)` I get:

```
df1.head()
Out[60]: 
        Date      Open      High       Low     Close     Volume   Market Cap
0 2018-03-14  0.789569  0.799080  0.676010  0.701902  479149000  30865600000
1 2018-03-13  0.798451  0.805729  0.778471  0.789711  279679000  31213000000
2 2018-12-03  0.832127  0.838328  0.787882  0.801048  355031000  32529500000
3 2018-11-03  0.795765  0.840407  0.775737  0.831122  472972000  31108000000
4 2018-10-03  0.854872  0.860443  0.793736  0.796627  402670000  33418600000
```

The format of Date originally is string dd-mm-yyyy, but as you can see, the tranformation to datetime messes things up from the 2nd row on. How can I get consistent datetimes?

Edit: I think I solved it. Using the answers below about format I found out the error was in a package that I used to generate the data ([`\[cryptocmd\]`](https://github.com/guptarohit/cryptocmd)). I changed the format to %Y-%m-%d in the utils script of the package and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: What happens with `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='raise', dayfirst=True)`? You haven't shown exactly what you started with

Comment: I can see in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html): "Warning: dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first (this is a known bug, based on dateutil behavior)." so it's probably better that you specify the format and just specify the format yourself (and maybe drop `dayfirst`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, there seems to be no change in the dateformat. I have tried various work arounds, but so far none worked. Among others trying a daterange for the length of the dataframe, with daily periods, but the original data is missing dates so it had in the end also the wrong index.

Comment: Can you give an example of failing data? Without seeing anything it's hard to say what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> dayfirst : boolean, default False
>
> Specify a date parse order if arg is str or its list-likes. If True,
>   parses dates with the day first, eg 10/11/12 is parsed as 2012-11-10.
>   **Warning: dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with**
>   **day first (this is a known bug, based on dateutil behavior).**

Emphasis mine. Since you apparently *know* that your format is "dd-mm-yyyy" you should specify it explicitly:

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='raise')
```